# React-router: ajax request onClick to Link

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router

These three links are tabs, each tab has an an ajax request `handleRequest` that is also called in `componentDidMount()`. I am confused when I clicked the tab at the first time it sends a request but wrong data will show but when I clicked it again the correct data shows. I wonder if I have misinterpret something about this react-router or somewhat else.

```
<Link to="/big-deals"
 className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === undefined})}
 onClick={this.handleRequest}>
  Most Popular
</Link>

<Link to="/big-deals"
  className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === 'best_seller'})}
  query={{ sort: 'best_seller' }}
  onClick={this.handleRequest}>
  Best Sellers
</Link>

<Link to="/big-deals"
 className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === 'new_arrival'})}
 query={{ sort: 'new_arrival' }}
 onClick={this.handleRequest}>
 New Arrivals
</Link>
```

Suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks

The rest of the code are shown below :)

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import bindActionCreators from 'utils/redux/bindActionCreators';

import { tagsSelector } from 'selectors/bigdeals';
import { getTags } from 'modules/tags';

import ProductPanel from './components/ProductPanel';

export default class BigDeals extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleRequest = ::this.handleRequest;
    this.handleTags = ::this.handleTags;
  }

  static propTypes = {
    actions: PropTypes.shape({
      getTags: PropTypes.func
    }).isRequired,

    products: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isFetchingError: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,

    // router state
    // primarily used for componentWillMount
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleRequest(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if ( nextProps.router === this.props.router ) {
      return;
    }
    this.handleRequest(nextProps);
  }

  render() {
   const {
      products,
      isFetching,
      isFetchingError,
      location,
      tagsSelector
    } = this.props;
    const { sort } = this.props.location.query;
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet title="Big Deals" />

        <div className="hero">
          <h1 className="heading">One Big Deals</h1>
          <h2 className="subheading">Get the most popular, best selling and new products now!</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="box-tabs">
            <Link to="/big-deals"
              className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === undefined})}
              onClick={this.handleRequest}>
              Most Popular
            </Link>
            <Link to="/big-deals"
              className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === 'best_seller'})}
              query={{ sort: 'best_seller' }}
              onClick={this.handleRequest}>
              Best Sellers
            </Link>

            <Link to="/big-deals"
              className={classnames('tab', { '-active': sort === 'new_arrival'})}
              query={{ sort: 'new_arrival' }}
              onClick={this.handleRequest}>
              New Arrivals
            </Link>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <ProductPanel
              view={location.query.view}
              products={products}
              isFetching={isFetching}
              isFetchingError={isFetchingError} />
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleRequest(props) {
    this.props.actions.getTags(this.props.tagsSelector, this.props.location.query.page);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.tags.collection,
  isFetching: state.tags.isFetching,
  isFetchingError: state.tags.isFetchingError,
  tagsSelector: tagsSelector(state),
  router: state.router
});

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ getTags }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(BigDeals);
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code for the rest of it to be able to say for sure :)

Comment: I edited the question sir and added the rest of the codes. It has many sub components including pagination :D

Comment: It's ma'am, but no problem ;) I can't help but wonder if the `onClick`/`handleRequest` is firing *before* the route transition. It might be interesting to log out `this.props.location.query` both in `handleRequest` and in `componentWillReceiveProps` to see if they differ.

Comment: I thought it was Michael hahaha sorry my bad :D. Wait lemme check

Comment: On the first load.
`handleRequest Object {}` and `componentWillReceiveProps Object {}` with the routes = `/category`. Then I clicked the `Best Seller` tab  and logs `handleRequest Object {}` , `componentWillReceiveProps Object {}` , `handleRequest Object {}` , and request success `componentWillReceiveProps Object {sort: "best_seller"}`

and I clicked the `Best Seller` once again , logs out `handleRequest Object {sort: "best_seller"}`, `componentWillReceiveProps Object {sort: "best_seller"}` and request success `componentWillReceiveProps Object {sort: "best_seller"}`

Answer (score 0):

One thing I just noticed: you take a `props` paremeter to `handleRequest`, but always use `this.props`. You probably want to use them conditionally:

```
  handleRequest(props) {
    props = props || this.props;
    props.actions.getTags(props.tagsSelector, props.location.query.page);
  }
```

The problem here is that `onClick` will pass the event as the first parameter, so `props` will never be falsy; you might need a separate handler for the `onClick` and for the change in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Also, based on your comment, I do think that the `onClick` is firing *before* the `query` prop changes, so you may need to defer calling the action, or only call the action when the component updates.